# Is Google App Engine ignoring my set_include_path?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

In past and current versions of PHP, I was able to set a path for a library like this:

```
define("ROOT", dirname(__FILE__));
set_include_path(ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "libraries" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "smarty" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

And it worked fine to do something like this:

```
require_once "Smarty.class.php";
spl_autoload_register(
    function($class) {
        if (!class_exists($class)) {
            require_once("$class.php");
        }
    }
);
$smarty = new Smarty();
etc...
```

However, now I'm attempting to use the Google App Engine, and I have to put:

```
require_once ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "libraries" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "smarty" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "Smarty.class.php";
```

and my auto-loader function no longer works for various other libraries.

In the console logs I get this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Smarty.class.php' (include_path='/base/data/home/apps/s~shiftedbits-cms/1.375217798547404203/source:/base/data/home/apps/s~shiftedbits-cms/1.375217798547404203/libraries/smarty:/base/data/home/apps/s~shiftedbits-cms/1.375217798547404203/libraries/swift:/base/data/home/apps/s~shiftedbits-cms/1.375217798547404203/libraries/html-purifier:/base/data/home/apps/s~shiftedbits-cms/1.375217798547404203/libraries/xhprof_lib:/base/data/home/apps/s~shiftedbits-cms/1.375217798547404203/source/modules/main:.;/base/data/home/apps/s~shiftedbits-cms/1.375217798547404203/;/base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk') in /base/data/home/apps/s~shiftedbits-cms/1.375217798547404203/bootstrap.php on line 70
```

despite the fact that Smarty.class.php is clearly uploaded and located in `/base/data/home/apps/s~shiftedbits-cms/1.375217798547404203/libraries/smarty`

which under normal circumstances is easily findable by PHP.

Do I need to do something special with my app.yaml file (below) to allow these files to be read by PHP, or are the restrictions on the instance too much that I need to find another way?

```
application: shiftedbits-cms
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg|ico))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg|ico)$

- url: /resources
  static_dir: resources

- url: /index\.html
  script: index.php

- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /(.+)$
  script: index.php`
```

Comment: How do you know "the fact that Smarty.class.php is clearly uploaded and located in... " is actually correct?

Comment: If I change nothing else, but the `require_once "Smarty.class.php"` to read `require_once "/full/path/to/Smarty.class.php"` then the error goes away and it moves on. The file is there.

Comment: To narrow down the issue, could you try 3 things? 1) use absolute path, temporarily. 2) use include instead of require (just for testing). 3) pre-pend 's~' to your ID (again, just to rule out that possibility)

Comment: The app engine has automatic class loading, so you do not need the require_once - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Automatic_class_loading

Comment: @George: 1.) As stated in the question, this already has been proven to work, even with require_once. The issue is that GAE is not finding the file in the inclusion path, despite the appropriate path being there. 2.) I get the following log: `17:04:54.253 PHP Warning:  include(): apc failed to locate Smarty.class.php - bailing in /base/data/home/apps/s~shiftedbits-cms/1.375305376631267622/bootstrap.php on line 70` 3.) It looks like it already is. Can you clarify where I should put it please?

Comment: @madebydavid If I do a simple `$s = Smarty();` after the set_include_path I get the following error in my logs `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Smarty' not found in /base/data/home/apps/s~shiftedbits-cms/1.375305456668420612/bootstrap.php on line 70`. This is why I am attempting to load Smarty.class.php because in the past, that's been the only way to get the class itself and the smarty auto-loader into memory, so that I could then register my own spl_autoload_register function.

Comment: @MikeS 1) Yeap, so it's a path problem 2) For this apc error, in your app.yaml, try adding in the "application_readable" flag. For instance -" url: /libraries
  static_dir: libraries
  application_readable: true "
so that the app can read that file. 3) in app.yaml, app ID

Comment: Have you debugged to find what the ROOT constant resolve's to?

Answer (score 0):

You must use a debug tool and find what the "ROOT" constant resolves to. Then replace ROOT with your basepath

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is related to your main problem but did you notice that your include path appear to mix unix path separators (":" at the beginning) and windows path separators (";" at the end) ?

(sorry to post this as an answer, my reputation is still too low to post comments :/)